# spring-boot-actuator startup error with spring MVC application?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-4, spring-boot-actuator

I am integrating `spring-boot-actuator` with `spring MVC 4.1.7` application.

Here is what I see with the in the `pom.xml`.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <!-- <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                     <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> -->
       </dependency>
```

I see the following in console when I make request to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/status`

```
WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/status] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'
```

Next, I tried excluding the `autoconfigure dependency` as follows.

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                     <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
       </dependency>
```

I get the following error during the container start-up:

```
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/metadata/DataSourcePoolMetadataProvider
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:572)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:475)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:677)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:621)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 32 more
Sep 09, 2015 7:00:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/metadata/DataSourcePoolMetadataProvider
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:572)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:475)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:677)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:621)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 32 more

Sep 09, 2015 7:00:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 09, 2015 7:00:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/GuestController] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 09, 2015 7:00:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2015-09-09 19:00:12,988 -0700 [CID:] [CONID:] [SWID:] [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 09 19:00:12 PDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-09-09 19:00:12,998 -0700 [CID:] [CONID:] [SWID:] [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 09 19:00:12 PDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-09-09 19:00:12,999 -0700 [CID:] [CONID:] [SWID:] [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 09 19:00:12 PDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Sep 09, 2015 7:00:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-2020"]
Sep 09, 2015 7:00:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3393 ms
```

If I remove the `spring-boot-actuator` dependency, the request works as expected 200 OK (`http://localhost:2020/myapp/status`)

**NOTE**: This is NOT a `spring-boot` application. but I am using spring-boot-actuator with `spring MVC 4.1.7`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you expect, but I believe that trying to integrate actuator without Spring Boot itself won't really work.

Many actuator features rely on:

- Boot's Conditional annotations
- Boot's dependency management
- Boot's webapp architecture (servlet configuration, etc)
- Boot's autoconfiguration
- and more...

You'll run into another problem after fixing the first one...